# iPhone does not get detected on older MacBook Pro

Tags: iphone, usb

I had to switch temporarily to a MacBook Pro 13 early 2011 model and when I'm connecting my iPhone 7+ or iPad, it's not getting detected nor charged.

Other USB devices like thumb drives or USB-microphones are working just fine.
If I put a voltcraft USB power converter between the iPhone/iPad and my MacBook Pro, the device is getting charged but it's still not getting detected in iTunes/duet. 
I already reset NVRAM (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) as suggested in similar posts here but that didn't fix anything and I don't know what else to try.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a known good USB > Lightning cable?

Comment: @IconDaemon yes, I've verified that first :) All cables that I've tried work fine on my iMac and Linux/Windows laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem before, and the following steps solved it for me:

1. Open iTunes
2. Plug the phone into the computer, and unlock the phone (Either with TouchID or Passcode Unlock)
3. A notification should popup on your phone saying "**Trust This Computer?**", click "**Trust**"
4. And finally, in iTunes and after a couple of seconds it should show up
   [image]

[image]

Comment: thank you now it works. I was waiting for the "Trust This Computer" prompt but it never showed up and the device wasn't even being charged. I've just tried it again with iTunes already being open and now it gets detected. thanks :)

Comment: You're quite welcome, but then that means I will have to change my answer slightly now 
If this helped you, please mark my answer as correct, and thanks!